# how Django reads http request and sends http response

Tags: python, c, django

If I write a simple http server in C. I can read http request through a file descriptor generated by `accept()` function in a while loop. And I can send http response to client through that file descriptor.

In Django I know the `HttpRequest` object will be passed to view function as a argument, but I want to know which function reads the `HttpRequest` through the socket and generate a `HttpRequest` object?

I know view function will return a `HttpResponse` object. But which function will send the actual http response to the client?

And where is the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't do this. It implements [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) standard and sits behind a WSGI server (such as Gunicorn or uWSGI) and lets it interact with sockets. If you want to learn more about it, you need to look up what's going on inside a wsgi server.

Comment: So when I type `python manage.py runserver` in terminal, starting development server at local host. Which WSGI server interacts with sockets?

Comment: @24April14, it uses [wsgiref.simple_server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) - simple wsgi server that comes with Python.